# JQuery add active class to parent class on reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My "active" class does not work when i replace "#" from href to an URL. When i click on the link, the page refresh and the "active" class does not change. 
This is the working code before i change # to URL.

```
<ul class="additional-menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="link2.1">Link2.1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.additional-menu a').on('click', function() {
var t = $(this);
t.parents('.additional-menu').find('li').removeClass('active'); 
t.parentsUntil('.additional-menu', 'li').addClass('active');
```

})

after changing(not working):

```
 <ul class="additional-menu">
 <li class="active"><a href="link1.php">Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="link1.php" id="link2">Link2</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="link2-1.php" id="link2.1">Link2.1</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="link3.php" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure what it is you want to do however it does appear that you will need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on a URL link, the page is being refreshed and the current Jquery wont work anymore. You have to update your codes to determine the active menu according to the page URL **on page load** or **on DOM ready** not **onClick**.

The you have to set the active class to the menu which has the found filename as href attribute.

Here is full code using jquery selectors:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var fullpath =window.location.pathname;
    var filename=fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    //alert(filename);
    var currentLink=$('a[href="' + filename + '"]'); //Selects the proper a tag
    currentLink.parent().addClass("active");
    }))
```

Comment: Do you mean i can't include this navigation? I have to copy and paste the code in every page i have and set the active class manually?

Comment: No you have not to set the active menu manually. I have updated the answer that how you can do this through JavaScript.

Comment: I am new to javaScript. Can you provide full solution according my code?

Comment: OK. I  added the proper code using Jquery selector.

Comment: Sorry. I used pathname incorrectly. Please check again.

Comment: Please write alert("filename"); after setting filename and tell me what you receive.

Comment: the filename works. filename:CHANZHEMING/fyp/doctor/headertest.php After clicking a link. filename:CHANZHEMING/fyp/doctor/link2.php

Comment: OK. getting filename updated. Please check again. Please notice that this works for single file name in href , not when href contains folders like **test/page.htm**

Comment: How can i add the "active" in <a> tag instead of <li>?